# Making a call to php with js, js stops at get request, both files work individually

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Sorry for my poor wording, I'm new to web technologies. I spent a few hours trying to figure out how to fix this and got no where, nothing happens when the page loads the do_something_with_sql.php doesn't run and the counter doesn't increment, yet both files work fine seperately.

```
<?php
echo "<p>Theoretical number of queries <div id =\"queries\">0</div></p>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
queries = 0;
count = 0;

function test()
{
    $.get("do_something_with_sql.php?count=" + count);

    count = count + 40;
    queries++;
    document.getElementById("queries").innerHTML = queries;
}

setInterval(test, 1000);


</script>
```

EDIT: This is the most recent update to the code and still it does nothing, there are no console errors, I have the JQuery file in the same folder too.

```
<?php
echo "<p>Theoretical number of queries <div id =\"queries\">0</div></p>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js">
    queries = 0;
    count = 0;

    function test()
    {
        $.get('does_something.php?count=' + count, function()
        {
            count = count + 40;
            queries++;
            document.getElementById('queries').innerHTML = queries;
            setTimeout(test, 1000);
        });

    }

    setTimeout(test, 1000);

</script>
```

EDIT EDIT:
Fixed and working version below.

```
<?php
echo "<p>Theoretical number of queries <div id =\"queries\">0</div></p>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    queries = 0;
    count = 0;

    function test()
    {
        $.get('does_something.php?count=' + count, function()
        {
            count = count + 40;
            queries++;
            document.getElementById('queries').innerHTML = queries;
            setTimeout(test, 1000);
        });

    }

    setTimeout(test, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it hangs"?  What *exactly* is happening?

Comment: `$.get("do_something_with_sql.php?=" + count);` you're not assigning `count` here.. `?=" + count` should be `?count=" + count`

Comment: Sone notes: 1) Do *NOT* pass `setInterval` a string.  It uses `eval`.  Do this: setInterval(test, 1000); 2) AJAX is *asynchronous*!  Your `count = count + 40;` and so on (and possibly your next interval) is happening *before* the AJAX call has completed.  You *need* to use callbacks when dealing with AJAX.

Comment: Have you defined the properties ajax should be using elsewhere in your code? 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ You not only need to provide the url as the first parameter, but it's expecting additional paramters. .get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
Perhaps it's not interpreting your string as a url?

Comment: @mable: When a parameter in documentation is shown in square braces, it means it's optional.  The 1st parameter to `$.get` is required, the others are optional.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I know it's optional. Apparently I misread something in his example. :)

Comment: right my bad I fked up this question :S

no I haven't touched ajax anywhere else, trying the setInterval thing now

Comment: Ok the setInterval is updated but has no effect. by hangs I mean it does nothing

Comment: @JaegerKor: "Does nothing" and "hangs" are two different things.  Do you see any messages/errors in your console?

Comment: @RocketHazmat more specifically it doesn't get past the get line, is that hanging?

Comment: @JaegerKor: My guess is it is crashing there and stopping execution (hanging is when you are stuck *waiting* for a task to finish).  Check your console for error messages.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Right, I'm really bad at this. undefined reference error $ is not defined

Comment: @JaegerKor: You need to include jQuery on your page.  That's what the `$` is.

Comment: @RocketHazmat cheers, if I don't care about the order in which the php calls happen should I still be using callbacks?

Comment: @JaegerKor: I'd suggest it, yes.  Just to make sure your AJAX call is complete before you trigger another one.  Instead of using `setInterval`, use `setTimeout`, then re-call `setTimeout` in the callback.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I get the feeling this is wrong but something like this? 


function loop()
    {
        setTimeout(test, loop());
    }
 
 loop();

Comment: @RocketHazmat ok, there are no more console errors, nothing is happening though

Comment: @JaegerKor: Yes, that is wrong.  You want something like this: `function test(){ $.get('url', function(){ setTimeout(test, 1000); });} setTimeout(test, 1000);`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I adapted the code and updated above, it doesn't count or run the php still :S there are no errors

Comment: @JaegerKor: Your code example is incorrect.  You need to make jQuery it's own `<script>` tag.  eg. `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script> <script> // put your code here</script>`

Comment: @RocketHazmat I don't understand it, but it fixed my code. Thank you for helping me out through all this, cheers once again.

Comment: @JaegerKor: `<script>` tags can *either* have an `src` **or** code inside them.  They ***cannot*** have both :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert but one thing's for sure, the line:

```
$.get("do_something_with_sql.php?=" + count);
```

Should be:

```
$.get("do_something_with_sql.php?count=" + count);
```